# How do I build an MS Project team with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have an MS Project Server 2010 running with a number of enterprise resources set up. I need to create a project via VBA, populate it with tasks and assign enterprise resources to tasks.

I am capable of creating tasks and assigning project resources to them, but I cannot assign enterprise resources. Once I create a new project, its resource list is empty. I can add enterprise resources to the project manually with TeamBuilder, and then they can be assigned, but I don't see a way to add enterprise resources to project via VBA. I tried to record a macro while adding resources, but it doesn't reflect the process and allows me only to open TeamBuilder.

How can I add enterprise resources to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did find an answer. It's `EnterpriseResourceGet` method of Project app. Probably it will save someone some nerve and let curse Microsoft a bit less. Getting resource UID via VBA is a different and fascinating story.